# How to determine that caught LibGit2SharpException is the HTTP 401 error?

Tags: libgit2sharp

When I try to fetch changes (*RepositoryExtensions.Fetch*) using invalid credentials *LibGit2Sharp* throws *LibGit2SharpException* with the following message:

```
An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Tag (Error).
Request failed with status code: 401
```

Since there might be other errors is there any way to determine that the exception is in fact HTTP 401 error without parsing the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think it is currently possible to get more specific information from that exception. This is something that would be a useful addition. Would you want to open an issue on the [LibGit2Sharp project](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) for this? If not, I will create one shortly.

Comment: Feel free to open an issue, jamill.